# Why didn't Kakyoin use his stand to communicate Dio's secret?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In s02e46 *Dio's World, Part 2* when, Dio mortally wounds Kakyoin and Kakyoin realizes his stand's power, why did he use Emerald Splash, knowing that the effort would immediately kill him? Granted he was mortally wounded, yeah, he didn't have much to lose, but wouldn't it be easier to simply communicate to Joseph via their stands?

It would a) obviously be less cryptic and b) require even less effort, because they seem to have been communicating through stands during battles and also wounded.

Therefore, why did he not explicitly tell Joseph about Dio's power and instead used Emerald Splash to crush the clock?

Comment: "communicate to Joseph vie their stands" I'm not quite sure how you think this would work? These stands aren't exactly know for their range or talking skills.

Comment: This feature was first introduced in SC ep6, where Jotaro and Tennille (fake captain) were able to communicate underwater through their stands. Presumably, this feature doesnt depend on stand range and/or talking skills since Jotaro was able to talk to Tennille while being some distance away in the whirl. Later in eps 23-24 when fighting with High Priestess, they communicate via their stands again while being underwater

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, it's much more interesting to see Kakyoin use his signature move one last time to reveal the secret behind DIO's stand. It would be less exciting to just have Hierophant Green slither over to Joseph and just speak to him. Plus, Kakyoin hardly had the strength to manifest Hierophant Green and perform his final Emerald Splash.

But you can also consider that DIO didn't want them to know that The World can stop time. He is more powerful if he knows their abilities but they don't know his. By using the Emerald Splash to destroy the clock-face, symbolizing the stopping of time, Kakyoin is able to tell Joseph about DIO's stand without DIO catching on. To DIO, it just looks like Kakyoin was trying to "go out with a bang," but Joseph knows Kakyoin personally, and realizes that he wouldn't do something so pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Because they were too far away, and as far as we know, Stand's speech works like regular speech, and they can't just talk to each other from far away.

Comment: Does it though? They did talk to each other while a) underwater and b) being inside the whirl and simultaneously underwater, as I mentioned in the comment to the question. Doesn’t really seem like regular speech

Comment: @NikitaNeganov I clarified: regular in terms distance, as far as far we know. Otherwise, Polenereff and Jotaro would have spoke while they were searching for the arrows in between Parts 3-4.